# Updated Twitter Direct Messages API with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Twitter updated their messages API (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event) today and all of the Python code I had written via Tweepy relating to sending Direct Messages has stopped working and I can't seem to get it to work. This is the code I have right now:

```
direct_message = api.send_direct_message(user=username, text=message_text)
```

However, I am getting the following error response from Twitter:

```
[{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist.'}]
```

I am confused about how to implement the new API changes with Tweepy. It was working perfectly fine until today and now it won't work... I am 100% sure the user is authenticated and has the permissions to send messages and I am still getting the error.

Comment: It looks like tweepy is not currently updated to support the new endpoints. There are some [open Github issues with some workarounds](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1081) that may help you, but until the library is updated it will not be very straightforward.

Comment: I´ve the same problem. We need to wait for tweepy update :-(

Comment: did you check with this workarounds available on GitHub? https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1081

Answer (score 0):

Update the Tweepy. In twitter app check permission to it. Revoke keys.
Now try this simples code.

```
 def direct_message(api):
 logger.info("Start send mensage")

 for dm in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids).items(10):
       #edit the msg parameter     
      api.send_direct_message(dm, 'Watching our new indie game trailer from my creator @AGTAStudios on Youtube : https://youtu.be/qGC-0toodmA')
      logger.info("msg send") 

def main():
    api = create_api()
    direct_message(api)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If it's dont work, reply with error.

Hope this helps.